# Hide everything in php before today excluding today

Tags: php, datetime

I am working on something events section and i wanted to hide all events which are older than today but i wanted the event to remain show until its over or until its next day..

the code i am using right now is

```
 if( strtotime($database_date) > strtotime('now') ) {

      echo 'something....';

}
```

The only problem with this code is that it hides the even which is currently on going TODAY so i wanted to hide the even when its over that will be next day.

I wanted to make my code work something like this:

```
strtotime($database_date) >= strtotime('now')
```

But this pops an php error

For example: Its Tuesday Today so i wanted to display all entries from database which date is greater than today but also display the entry for today.. and hide all entries before today.

Comment: so you want to ignore the TIME but keep the day comparison? as your pulling things out of the db, you should do this in the query

Comment: If time is less than something, then do this; in a nutshell.

Comment: No actually my code hide all older events, and display events which are > today, i wanted to just add an exception which will also show events of today

Comment: Then use `==` instead of `>=`

Comment: already tried but it pops php error

Comment: how about instead of `now`, use `yesterday`

Comment: Thanks so much.. how i can be so dumb..!!! it was simply "yesterday"

Comment: when all your troubles seemed so far away.